# odbc causes Rscript.exe to crash - R for windows front-end has stopped working

Tags: r, odbc, system, dbi, rscript

For several years I have use the system function to run an R script via Rscript.exe, in order to load MS Access tables from within a 64-bit R window (RODBC works only with 32-bit, apparently). Although this has worked for years, it no longer does so. Example code is:

```
    script_path <- "C:/Users/staufge/Documents/script.r"
    sink(script_path)
    cat("
    library(RODBC)
    setwd('C:/Users/staufge/Documents') 
    # define path to database
    path <- 'C:/Users/staufge/Documents/Database.accdb'
    ch <- odbcConnectAccess2007(path) 
    tb1 <- sqlFetch(ch, 'Table1',stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 
    close(ch)
    # save the tables
    save.image(file = 'out.RData')
    ",fill=TRUE)
    sink()  
    ## invoke R commands in 32 bit R
    system(command=paste(file.path(R.home(), "bin", "i386", "Rscript.exe"), script_path,sep=" "))
    load("C:/Users/staufge/out.RData")
```

Now, when I run that system function, it appears to generate the output, but then Rscript.exe immediately crashes with the message described in the title.

I also tried an alternative with the same results.

```
script_path <- "C:/Users/staufge/Documents/script.r"
sink(script_path)
cat("
library(DBI)
library(odbc)
setwd('C:/Users/staufge/Documents') 
# define path to database
path <- 'C:/Users/staufge/Documents/Database.accdb'
ch = dbConnect(odbc(), .connection_string = paste0('Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=', path, ';'))
df1 <- dbReadTable(ch , 'table1')
close(ch)
# save the tables
save.image(file = 'out.RData')
",fill=TRUE)
sink()  
## invoke R commands in 32 bit R
system(command=paste(file.path(R.home(), "bin", "i386", "Rscript.exe"), script_path,sep=" "))
load("C:/Users/staufge/out.RData")
```

I'll also note that when I just just open a 32-bit R window, and establish the connection directly and run the query (without invoking Rscript.exe), it works, and R does not crash. One other note is that when the script does not try to establish a connection, then there is no problem. So it is RODBC (or odbc) that is causing the problem.

I suppose for this problem, I could just work in 32-bit R, but I am curious why this used to work, but now crashes Rscript.exe.

Comment: A common debugging practice would be to try and execute narrowed-down versions of your script line by line till you find which one causes the crash. What happens for example if you use `saveRDS(df1, 'df1.rds')` (or `openxlsx::write.xlsx` or similar) instead of `save.image`?

Comment: FYI, the 32-/64-bit thing is because of Microsoft: their ODBC drivers for Access must be the same bit-ness as the version of the underlying Access DLLs (typically via Office), which is usually 32-bit. For similar reasons I think, anything that wants to use the 32-bit ODBC drivers for something must also be in 32-bit land. If you could stomach the nightmare (and overhead and _risk_) of uninstalling your 32-bit Office and reinstalling the 64-bit version, then installing the 64-bit Access ODBC drivers (I think they exist), you _might_ be able to use 64-bit R to do this. _Might_. Caveat emptor.

Comment: @gaut Thanks for the suggestions. It is clearly the "ch = ..." line that causes the crash. The interesting thing is that save.image works (the output is created), and then Rscript crashes. This was a problem, because I was invoking the script from within a larger function, which aborted when Rscript crashed. My [somewhat unsatisfactory] solution, for now, is to break the function into two functions. Then I just let Rscript crash, and then I load in the output it created before it crashed, and I'm on my way again.

Comment: @r2evans Unfortunately (or maybe fortunately!) uninstalling 32-bit Office and installing 64-bit is out of the question. Eventually it might be best to leave Access for a different platform.

Comment: I agree on both counts: the reason I wrote that comment was to provide a little context and explain the (herculean) change that should allow it to work, but I did try the 64-bit office years ago and it breaks compatibility with many other things that this was not worth it for me. As for another method, might I recommend SQLite or DuckDB? I'm not sure how much liberty you have.